# Sorting column by double clicking is mixing the order

Tags: excel, vba

I have data that shows Name in a column, then different numbers in the other columns. When I double click on a header cell, it sorts the column in a descending order. This works but then all the names aren't matching up with its value anymore and I can't figure out why.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim KeyRange As Range
Dim ColumnCount As Integer
Dim lrow As Long

lrow = Sheets("Tracker").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next

    ColumnCount = Range("B5:Q" & lrow).Columns.Count
        Cancel = False
    If Target.Row = 5 And Target.Column <= ColumnCount Then
        Cancel = True
        Worksheets("Backend").Range("C1") = Target.Value

        Set KeyRange = Range(Target.Address)

        Range("B5:Q" & lrow).sort Key1:=KeyRange, Header:=xlYes, Order1:=xlDescending
        Worksheets("Backend").Range("A1") = Target.Column
        Worksheets("Backend").Calculate
            For i = 1 To ColumnCount
            Range("B5:Q" & lrow).Cells(1, i).Value = Worksheets("Backend").Range("A4").Offset(0, i - 1).Value
            Next i
    End If

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not with the code but with the formulas within the table. 
See: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/index-match-breaks-when-sorting/c848e231-9e53-4a8d-a5f6-f4bf1b9f0a12

Comment: Select your answer, please to help others when they meet the same problem [About selecting an aswer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

You did not include the names column in the range to be sorted.

You have

`Range("B5:Q" & lrow).sort Key1:=KeyRange, Header:=xlYes, Order1:=xlDescending`

But it should be

`Range("A5:Q" & lrow).sort Key1:=KeyRange, Header:=xlYes, Order1:=xlDescending`

---

**Edit 1:**

Since Names is in column B, not A as I assumed then maybe multiple sorting are being applied over each other. To eliminate this probability, please try sorting using the sheet object instead of the range object (after clearing old sorting).

This is how

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim KeyRange As Range
    Dim ColumnCount As Integer
    Dim lrow As Long

    lrow = Sheets("Tracker").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next

    ColumnCount = Range("B5:Q" & lrow).Columns.Count
    Cancel = False
    If Target.Row = 5 And Target.Column <= ColumnCount Then
        Cancel = True

        Worksheets("Backend").Range("C1") = Target.Value

        With Me
            .Sort.SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Target, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Sort.SetRange .Range("B5:Q" & lrow)
            .Sort.Header = xlYes
            .Sort.MatchCase = False
            .Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Sort.Apply
        End With


        With Worksheets("Backend")
            .Range("A1") = Target.Column
            .Calculate
            For i = 1 To ColumnCount
                Range("B5:Q" & lrow).Cells(1, i).Value = .Range("A4").Offset(0, i - 1).Value
            Next i
        End With

    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: The names column is in column B